# iOS 7: Sharing in iOS 7 has cut of icons in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios7

**I have sharing functionality in my app. I have used UIActivityViewController. But in iOS 7 the share icons are cut of..**

[image]

I have used Following code:

NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strTitle];
        [title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                      value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]
                      range:NSMakeRange(0,strTitle.length)];

```
CustomActivityView *ActivityProvider = [[CustomActivityView alloc] init];
ActivityProvider.strToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><b>%@</b><br>%@<br><br></html>",title.string,someText];
NSArray *Items = @[ActivityProvider];
NSArray *act = @[];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:Items
                                  applicationActivities:act];

[self presentModalViewController:activityViewController animated:YES];
```

**I have used Custom Activity controller:**

```
@interface CustomActivityView : UIActivityItemProvider
{
    NSString *strToShare;
    NSString *shareTitle;

}

@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *strToShare;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *shareTitle;


@end


@interface CustomActivityView ()

@end

@implementation CustomActivityView
@synthesize strToShare,shareTitle;

- (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
          itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{

    if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] )
    {


   }

    else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ){

    }
    else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage] ){

  }

    else if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] ){
  }
    else{
 }


    return nil;
}





@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are subclassing the UIActivity(ies) and overriding "activityImage", make sure that the image you are returning is the right size (It seems that yours is 1x?). Also the image you supply should be a mask and not the icon itself.